# Breaking a list and tagging each element with an index number

Tags: erlang

How does one split a list which is passed as an argument to a function and tag each element with a number?

The problem I have is how to increment in erlang as there are no for loops.

Thanks

Comment: There are no loops, but there is recursion ! So, just increment your var when calling recursively your function !

Comment: There are actually for loops. See lists:foreach.

Comment: I know there is recursion. I am asking how does one split a list which is passed as an argument to a function and tag each element with a number?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want for input and output? How do you define split? Which number do you want to use to tag the elements? How do you want your elements tagged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
tagger(List) ->
    tagger(List, 0).
tagger([Head|Tail], Index) ->
    [{Head, Index}|tagger(Tail, Index + 1)];
tagger([], _Index) ->
    [].
```

Because if it is, you can use `lists:mapfoldl`:

```
lists:mapfoldl(fun (A, AccIn) -> {{A, AccIn}, AccIn + 1} end, 0, List).
```

Comment: Thanks. this is what I was trying to do. But not using BIFs.

Comment: 1st, BIFs are not dangerous, and if this is course work, please ask your supervisor. 2nd the example above is first of all wrong and secondly unnecessarily complicated. An easier (correct) solution is lists:zip(lists:seq(1, length(List)), List).

Comment: @Daniel Luna: The second example looks good to me. It only traverses the list once, while yours traverses it twice, plus it also builds a throw-away list of numbers.